# Assign DataSet to Local Variables

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataset

I am running a SQL Query and returning a `DataSet` - I want to iterate the info in the `DataSet` and assign the values to local variables.  I have confirmed that my `DataSet` returns rows but my variables are not getting assigned for some reason.  Can someone look at my syntax and assist with why this is occurring?

```
protected void GetSomeData()
{
  string employeeid = this.txtemployeeid.Text;
  DataSet empinfo = new DataSet();
  empinfo = RunSqlQuery(employeeid);
  this.txtemployeefirstname = empinfo.Tables[0].Rows[0]["employeefirstname"].ToString());
  this.txtemployeelastname = empinfo.Tables[0].Rows[1]["employeelastname"].ToString());
  this.txtemployeeaddress = empinfo.Tables[0].Rows[2]["employeeaddress"].ToString());
  this.txt.employeephone = empinfo.Tables[0].Rows[3]["employeephone"].ToString());
}
public DataSet RunSqlQuery(string employeeid)
{
  string sqlQuery = "Select employeefirstname, employeelastname, employeeaddress, employeephone from abcd where employeeid = "+employeeid+" and employeeid is not null";
  try
  {             
      connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[connectionString].ToString();   
      sqlDatabaseConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
      sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, sqlDatabaseConnection);
      sqlDatabaseConnection.Open();
      sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 0;        
      dataSet = new DataSet();
      sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);            
      sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "Data");
      return dataSet;
  }
  catch (Exception exception)
  {
      throw exception;
  }
  finally
  {
      sqlDatabaseConnection.Close();
      sqlCommand.Dispose();
      sqlDataAdapter.Dispose();
  }
```

}

**EDIT**
By variables not getting assigned, I mean when I step through my code, it seems that the value returned from the database is not being populated into the `empinfo.Tables[0].Rows[0]["employeefirstname"].ToString());` they are always null.

Comment: Well it's not clear why you're creating a new DataSet and assigning it to empinfo and then ignoring that value and reassigning it, nor why you have a pointless catch block. (I'd also just use `using` statements instead of manually closing the connection etc, and use local variables for the SQL resources, but that's a different matter.) You haven't told us what you're actually observing though, which makes it hard to help you.

Comment: What do you mean not assigned? Null? Errors?

Comment: @AndyWiesendanger - when I step through my code all (employeefirstname, employeelastname, employeephone, employeeaddress) are null.

Comment: In empinfo? Or the textboxes? You verified empinfo.Tables[0].Rows[0] has data?

Comment: @AndyWiesendanger - the textboxes, empinfo.Tables[0].Rows[0] has data.

Comment: Ok, though seems like your update is stating the opposite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assigning the value to the textbox (at least, I assume txtemployeefirstname is a textbox). I think you mean txtemployeefirstname.text?